# BingX api how to trade order in perpetual swap api v2?

Tags: python, trading

I'm trying to place a new order using BingX API in python but I get this response:
`{"code":100001,"msg":"","success":false,"timestamp":1674818924644}`

I use the following code to trade a new order:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import base64
import hmac
import time
import json

APIURL = "https://open-api.bingx.com"
APIKEY = "MyApiKEY"
SECRETKEY = "MySecretKey"

def genSignature(paramsStr):
    return hmac.new(SECRETKEY.encode("utf-8"),
        paramsStr.encode("utf-8"), digestmod="sha256").digest()

def post(url, body):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'X-BX-APIKEY': APIKEY,
    }, method="POST")
    return urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()

def tradeOrder(symbol, side, tradeType):
    paramsMap = {
        "symbol": symbol,
        "side": side,
        "type": tradeType,
        "timestamp": int(time.time()*1000),
    }
    paramsStr = "&".join(["%s=%s" % (k, paramsMap[k]) for k in paramsMap])
    paramsStr += "&signature=" + genSignature(paramsStr).hex()
    url = "%s/openApi/swap/v2/trade/order?%s" % (APIURL, paramsStr)
    return post(url, paramsStr)

def main():
    tradeOrder("BTC-USDT", "BUY", "MARKET")

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

What's wrong with this code? 
I'm using the api v2, here's the [link](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/swapV2/)